# sql server 2016 availability group listener works but missing in sys.availability_group_listeners

Tags: sql-server

Due to a complex environment with strict separation of duties, we were unable to add a SQL Server 2016 availability group listener using t-sql or SSMS. The systems admin added it using Windows Failover Cluster Manager on Windows Server 2012 R2. We've done that several times in the past for SQL Server 2012. The listener works (can connect, failovers work). However, it doesn't show in SSMS and SELECT * FROM sys.availability_group_listeners doesn't return anything.

Any ideas on how to get the listener to show in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it in `sys.availability_group_listener_ip_addresses`?

Comment: No, that doesn't return anything either.

Comment: Sorry, I figured this out. After creating the listener, a dependency must be added to the AG resource in Windows Failover Cluster Manager to make the AG dependent upon the listener.